# Put long formulas on new line/pgf tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, line-breaking

Sometimes I have to work with long formulas that can (or I want) not be split over two lines.
I'm trying to write a macro that sent the formula at the new line if the formula would go over the margin.
For example, with lines of twenty characters, and calling `\Foo` this macro:
a text like

> 12345678901234567890
>   aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa $bbbbbb$
>   aaaaa aaaa

is formatted as

> 12345678901234567890
>   aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa bbbbbb
>   aaaaa aaaa

while

> 12345678901234567890
>   aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa \Foo{$bbbbbb$}
>   aaaaa aaaa

is formatted as

> 12345678901234567890
>   aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa
>   bbbbbb aaaaa aaaa

Since this require to verify if such macro is over the limit after printing,
I suppose is something requiring multiple step of compilation.
The only way I know to retrieve coordinates of a point is using a `tikz` coordinate, but
so a "pseudocode" draft of what I'm trying to do is:

```
\newcommand{\Foo}[1]{%
  \myCount=\myCount+1
  \if\NameConcat\FooVar\myCount>\pageLength\endline\else\relax
  #1%
  \coordinate\NameConcat\FooVar\myCount%
  }
```

(at the start `\myCount` and all `\FooVars` have to be "zero", and `\NameConcat` concatenate the `FooVar` name and the counter creating as many counter as needed)

So, what is the best way to implement this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it so complicated. You can just put the formula or any other text in a `\mbox{...}` to prevent it from being broken across lines:

```
12345678901234567890
aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa \mbox{$bbbbbb$}
aaaaa aaaa
```

Comment: NO, if I do so I obtain that it goes OUTSIDE the maximum line size, out of the border of the page/coloumn. What I want is to **automatically** go on a new line in that case.

Comment: @macro: That's not always the case but depends on the line content. You can influence this by modifying some penalties. You can also put `\linebreak[3]` in front of `\mbox`, best as part of a macro, to pursue LaTeX to break the line there if required.

Comment: Sorry for the long time for the reply. It is not working either. Below there is a better explanation.